# Twitter API V2 create tweet with media PHP

Tags: php, twitter

After some time I figure out how to create tweet with the new API V2, but with the new version doesn't have the possibility to send media with the text. This is my code to send simple text, but I really needs to create with an image.

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);

$data =  [
   'text' => 'Hello world'
];

$connection->setApiVersion('2');
$content = $connection->post("tweets", $data, true);

var_dump($content);
```

I am using the twitteroauth.com to install just use:

```
composer require abraham/twitteroauth
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution... here is the code for create a tweet with media... it's necessary to upload the media using the API V1 and after with the id create the tweet with V2...

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;


$connection = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);


$image = [];

$media = $connection->upload('media/upload', ['media' => 'image/test.jpg']);
array_push($image, $media->media_id_string);

$data =  [
    'text' => 'Hello world',
    'media'=> ['media_ids' => $image]
];


$connection->setApiVersion('2');
$content = $connection->post("tweets", $data, true);

var_dump($content);
```

Below got a pic with the tokens you need to use, only this:

[image]

Comment: I've got the same problem! I do not understand where the bearer token is used here? Or did you get the accessToken with the old oauth flow?

Comment: You dont need to use bearer token, just use the consumer key / consumer secret and access token / access token secret - I will update the answer with the print ;)

Comment: does uploading a video work for you? I get: Operation timed out after 5070 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

Comment: I am not using the API to upload videos, only pics. I don't know about this issue, maybe the file size or something

Comment: it work for me but you need to set the api version $connection->setApiVersion('1.1'); before upload media

Comment: can you use this endpoint on the Free tier of the Twitter API? or at least we need the Basic?